# MySQL where clause that should not work but returns all table contents

Tags: mysql

This query is returning all the table contents. To me is not a valid where clause. Anyone have any idea why this works?

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, TRUE is a costant value = 1, while FALSE is = 0, your query is then eqivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TRUE
```

also, all conditions are converted either to 0 or to 1:

```
SELECT 'a' = 'a'
```

will return 1, while

```
SELECT 'a' = 'b'
```

will return 0 so for example the following queries are all equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TRUE
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 'a' = 'a'
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 1
```

but every value <> 0 is considered true as well, so even this will return all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 2
```

but if a value <> is considered true, one would expect the following query to work:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE 2 = TRUE
```

but this won't return anything, because 2 = 1. Yes, sometimes MySQL is a little weird.

Comment: Thought about that but this as the same result: SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 1536636737

Answer (score 0):

Select * from TableName where 1 is equivalent with Select * from TableName because it mens where true